# Difference between 'decided on' and 'decided to'?

Tags: differences, prepositions, infinitives

***Examples:***

*I have decided on a blue carpet for the bedroom.

I have decided to emigrate to Australia.*

What exactly is the difference between "decided on" and "decided to"? Is the usage simply based on construction of the sentence, or do they differ in meaning as well?

Comment: Hello Sam! Adding to the excellent answer, I should also say that "making a decision for no reason" is probably possible since to decide something involves not only considering things, so decisions are a bit indipendent from prepositions! However, congratulations: +1

Comment: Shouldn't the question be "decide on" vs "decide **up**on"?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have decided on + **object**

I have decided to + **verb**

The usage is based on the construction of the sentence. You *could* say:

> I have decided *to buy* a blue carpet for the bedroom.
>   I have decided *on
>   emigrating [or emigration]* to Australia.

**EDIT**

As mentioned in John Lawler's comment, there is a subtle difference between the two. ***Decide to*** suggests that you have chosen a plan of action.

> I have decided to emigrate to Australia.

I might have been considering staying at home, or I might have been considering other countries, but at any rate, this is what I am going to do.

***Decide on*** suggests that you have chosen one from two or more options that you were weighing.

> I have decided on emigration. I am going to Australia. (OR – I have
>   decided to emigrate to Australia.)

I was considering England, Canada and Australia, but I have finally chosen Australia.

Comment: Though there is a small wrinkle in the fact that they can both take complement clauses: _on_ with a gerund (_I decided on going to Australia_) vs a normal infinitive (_I decided to go to Australia_). Generally, when compared, _decide on_ invites the inference that the object is one of several possible choices, while _decide to_ is non-committal -- sort of parallel to the difference between _which_ and _what_ in _Which/What trip did you take?_

Comment: Thank you for that @JohnLawler -- I will edit accordingly.

Comment: @JAM, "decide on" can mean "decide in favour of X" (see John Lawler and your edit) *or* "arrive at a decision about X", as in decide on admissions criteria. "decide on" selects a N, V-ing, wh-CL, and wh to-INF.