# "Decide/Intend on [gerund]" vs. "decide/intend to [infinitive]"

Tags: grammar, american-english, word-usage, colloquialisms

In analogy with "plan on [gerund]", do the gerund constructions above have any currency in AE, or are these chiefly dialectal and might sound folksy to most ears?

E.g.

> We decided on taking our next vacation to France.
>
> We decided to take our next vacation to France.

.

> We're intending on visiting Italy on our next vacation.
>
> We're intending to visit Italy on our next vacation.

Comment: The 'decide on V-ing' / 'decide to V' question has been answered [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78170/difference-between-decided-on-and-decided-to). 'Intending on' sounds unnatural to my (British, admittedly) ears, and seems very rare in [US literature](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=intending+to%2Cintending+on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cintending%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cintending%20on%3B%2Cc0); Collins Cobuild does not acknowledge the usage. Though there are quite a few Google hits.

Comment: U.S. English speaker here. I think that "We're intending on visiting Italy on our next vacation" sounds folksy in a bad way. I would be somewhat happier with "We're intending a visit to Italy for our next vacation" if you dislike the straightforward "We're intending to visit..." for some reason; but to me "We're intending to visit..." sounds significantly better than either alternative. I suspect that the tripwire here is that "planning on" is itself idiomatic in a way that doesn't permit a straight substitution of "intending" for "planning" without producing awkward results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Australian British English speaker here. I use both in different contexts, nuance tends to alter the meaning of 'intending'.

For example:

"I'm intending on finding a job soon" - intending/relying.

"I'm intending to be there on time" - intending/expecting.

(Not claiming this to be grammatically correct though!)

Comment: Which do you speak, Australian or British?